# Building a new variable from a byte list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, types, type-conversion

I am trying to write a data logger GUI. This application receives information over serial port about the variables that are defined in an embedded software.

I have a class for storing these variables. A new instance of this class is created everytime a new variable is requested in watch-window.

```
public class Var_t
{
    public string vType;    //variable type chosen from a combobox      
    public string vName;    //variable name read from the serial port
    public UInt32 vAddr;    //variable ram addr read from the serial port
    public byte vSize;      //variable size read from the serial port
    public List<byte> vBuffer;    //variable content buffer  
};
```

Since the variable size and type are read dynamically at the runtime, I'm just filling the `byte` `List` while receiving the value of this variable.

I need a class that combines these bytes using the `vType` datatype after the transfer is completed. This class will return a string to let me show the variable value in a combo-box to the user:

```
public class BuildVariable(List<byte> varBuf, string varType)
{
    string ValueStr;

    //I tried using BitConverter to combine the bytes into a new object 
    //but it does not accept any parameter for the type

    return ValueStr;
};
```

Possible variable types are `byte`, `uint8`, `int8`, `uint16`, `int16`, `uint32`, `int32`, `uint64`, `int64`, `float`, `double`,`char`,`string`

Comment: Simplest way is to simply switch on vType or use a dictionary with vType as key & a BitConverter lambda as value.

Comment: I'm not very experienced in C# actually. I know how and why we use the dictionary but I don't know much about lambda. Would you please give me an example or a reference about what you mean? Do you think I should add an example to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
public static string GetTypedString(Var_t varToDisp)
{
    string ValueDisplay;

    switch (varToDisp.vType)
    {
        case "byte":

            lock (varToDisp.value)
            {
                byte temp_byte = varToDisp.vBuffer[0];
                ValueDisplay = temp_byte.ToString();
            }
            break;

        case "uint16":

            lock (varToDisp.value)
            {
                UInt16 temp_ui16 = BitConverter.ToUInt16(varToDisp.vBuffer.ToArray<byte>(), 0);
                ValueDisplay = temp_ui16.ToString();
            }
            break;

        case "uint32":

            lock (varToDisp.value)
            {
                UInt32 temp_uint32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(varToDisp.vBuffer.ToArray<byte>(), 0);
                ValueDisplay = temp_uint32.ToString();
            }
            break;

        //and so on..
    }

    return ValueDisplay;
}
```

I couldn't find a way to do it with a dynamic type selection, so I had to do the conversion one by one.